# ZSH Agnoster Theme showing machine name

Tags: shell, ubuntu, zsh, digital-ocean, oh-my-zsh

I have a development server hosted on Digital Ocean, using Ubuntu 14.04.  I switched my shell to ZSH and decided to go with the **Agnoster** theme.  In order to get `user@hostname` to stop showing, I set the `DEFAULT_USER` in my .zshrc file.

For some reason on the ubuntu server, that's not working.  The hostname still shows, and will not go away.  I'm doing the exact same thing on my Mac OSX, and it works fine.

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Anyone know what's going on? I even tried `DEFAULT_USER="$USER@$HOST"` with no luck.

If I go back to the default, **Robby Russell** theme, it works just fine.

[image]

Answer (score 99, accepted):

It is the feature according to [this](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/00ec11d3c0a2b2b7413ad84940ddec299aafbb04/themes/agnoster.zsh-theme#L63); when we are `ssh`ing, the hostname will be shown.

Overriding the function `prompt_context` or `build_prompt` on **Agnoster** theme will rescue. Putting below snippets at the very end of the `~/.zshrc` for example.

```sh
# redefine prompt_context for hiding user@hostname
prompt_context () { }
```

Answer (score 73):

Here is my version from first two answers. They explain very clearly. I will merge again.

1. step 1. open your `.zshrc` file by `vim .zshrc`
2. step 2. go to end of your file.
3. Paste this code:

*careful indent again your code*

```
prompt_context() {
  if [[ "$USER" != "$DEFAULT_USER" || -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ]]; then
    prompt_segment black default "%(!.%{%F{yellow}%}.)$USER"
  fi
}
```

Reference link: [agnoster theme code](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/00ec11d3c0a2b2b7413ad84940ddec299aafbb04/themes/agnoster.zsh-theme#L63)

Hope this help :)

Comment: This should be approved answer, he do not modify library source code that could be a problem later on.

Comment: Agreed, this is the most helpful answer ^_^

Answer (score 32):

I'm using agnoster theme too.

Edit `agnoster.zsh-theme` and find `$user@%m` and delete `@%m`.

Image sample:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But I think this one is for local machine (mac) but will not work on a server as the original question was asking. For a local Mac machine, you also need to source that filename afterwards. Type: "source agnoster.zsh-theme" in the command line without the double quotes.

Answer (score 15):

My config in `~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/agnoster.zsh-theme`

```
prompt_context() {
  # Custom (Random emoji)
  emojis=("⚡️" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "")
  RAND_EMOJI_N=$(( $RANDOM % ${#emojis[@]} + 1))
  prompt_segment black default "${emojis[$RAND_EMOJI_N]} "
}
```

Comment: Such a great idea

Answer (score 13):

You can set `DEFAULT_USER="[user name]"` in your `.zshrc` file and it will stop showing the `user@hostname` in your terminal.

In order to get the `[user name]`, type `id -un` in your terminal and it will output the `[user name]` value.

Comment: $DEFAULT_USER was empty on cygwin, might also be on some linux boxes. Add to first line of .zshrc ``export DEFAULT_USER=`id -un` ``

Answer (score 9):

If you're on **macOS**, the addition of a single line to your `~/.zshrc` file is enough to hide the machine name in the Terminal:

```
# Where we specify the theme
ZSH_THEME="agnoster"
# Force yourself as the system's default user
DEFAULT_USER="$(whoami)"
```

This will negate the `"$user" != "$DEFAULT_USER"` check [here](https://github.com/agnoster/agnoster-zsh-theme/blob/master/agnoster.zsh-theme#L76), thereby hiding the machine name locally while still displaying it for SSH connections.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your .zshrc file before the 'source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh'

```
DEFAULT_USER=drewr
```

I use Agnoster as well, and this is what I put to take away the username from displaying.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

We needn't edit `agnoster.zsh-theme` but append the code below at the end of `.zshrc`:

```
export USER=''
prompt_context() {
  if [[ "$USER" != "$DEFAULT_USER" || -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ]]; then
    prompt_segment black default "%(!.%{%F{yellow}%}.)$USER"
  fi
}
```

we can change `export USER=''` like `export USER='john'` to show what we want.

Answer (score 1):

1.
open ~/.zshrc
add line:
DEFAULT_USER=`whoami`  or export DEFAULT_USER= myusername (mac os x)

2.
open ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/agnoster.zsh-theme files.

find ## Main prompt 
add # for prompt_context  line.

Answer (score 1):

Related to the context:
Sometimes sourcing the zshrc by "source ~/.zshrc" might not work. Start a new terminal to see the updated changes.

Answer (score 1):

Although the accepted answer is perfectly fine, I prefer to modify my `.zshrc` file as little as I can to keep things clean.

So, a slightly different approach would be to override the theme (as recommended on https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Customization#overriding-and-adding-themes).

1. Go to your `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/themes` folder
2. Create a file called `agnoster.zsh-theme`
3. Add your customization and save (for example, here, redefine the `prompt_context()` so it does nothing):

```
prompt_context() {}
```

4. Update your terminal with your changes:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
prompt_context() {
  # Custom (Random emoji)

  MINUTE_TRC=$(date +%M)
  emojis_1=("" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "")
  emojis_2=("" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "️")    

  if (($MINUTE_TRC % 2 != 0)); then
    RAND_EMOJI_N=$(( $RANDOM % ${#emojis_1[@]} + 1))
    prompt_segment black default "%(!.%F{red}.%F{red})%n%F{green}@%F{Blue}%m %F{reset} ${emojis_1[$RAND_EMOJI_N]} "
  else
    RAND_EMOJI_N=$(( $RANDOM % ${#emojis_2[@]} + 1))
    prompt_segment black default "%(!.%F{red}.%F{red})%n%F{green}@%F{green}%m %F{reset} ${emojis_2[$RAND_EMOJI_N]} "
  fi
}
```

Improvement on Pongsatorn Nitithammawoot config. This will make the emoji change every min.